# How to get last call from/to contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to retrieve some contacts info. by now what i am using is in this style to get contact's name, phone, organization and email.

```
{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}
```

But i have not found a similar simple way to get the last call to/from contact (last time contacted, if you want) so i would appreciate any help

thank you all

Comment: so you want a mapping of each contact with the details of last time contacted, call call from, last call to?

Comment: yes, that would work. But what I need is easier since I need last time contacted of ONE previously retrieved contact, and not all of them